# Garden with mushrooms

Tags: combinatorics

A farmer cultivates mushrooms in his garden. A greedy neighbor wants to pick some but the farmer is trying to block him.

The garden has the form of a 8x6 grid. Rows 1 to 8 from the front to the back and columns A to F from left to right. The mushrooms are planted in the 8th row (6 mushrooms). The farmer is initially standing at the block E7, right in front of the mushrooms and can move at any of his direct surrounding 8 blocks (including those behind him, where the mushrooms are planted). 
The neighbor initially stands at block F1 and is trying to reach the mushrooms by walking at any of his directly surrounding blocks (including those situated diagonally in relation to his position). Once the neighbor reaches the farmer, he hits him and can then reach the mushrooms, but if the farmer reaches the neighbor, he hits him also, and he has to back out. The neighbor moves first and then they alternate turns. Will he manage to get at least one mushroom, or the farmer will block him? 
To summarize, the "game" ends in any of the 3 cases:

1. The farmer reaches the neighbor (walks on his square). In this case, the neighbor has to leave and go home.
2. The neighbor reaches the farmer, even once (walks on his square). Then the farmer has to admit he lost, and let him get the mushrooms!
3. The neighbor reaches one (any) mushroom before the farmer manages to stop him.

Describe some of the optimal moves for each of them, using the grid coordinates. 
[image: Garden]

I tried to set the neighbor "chase" the farmer by trying to be on the same column with him but can't find a general pattern.

FYI I found this in an Ukrainian magazine at the Kiev airport - I hope I translated everything correctly!

Comment: Looks like a two-kings chess problem, opposition and distant opposition. That would imply that the neighbour's best move is E1.

Comment: What does "back off" mean here?

Comment: @LukasKofler I changed it to "back out". If the farmer reaches him (even once) the neighbor must leave.

Comment: It seems to me that just as the farmer wins by hitting the neighbor even once before the neighbor gets a mushroom, the neighbor wins either by getting a mushroom before being hit or by hitting the farmer before being hit by the farmer.

Comment: @hardmath I didn't quite understand your comment. Can you please explain further? Thank you!

Comment: I'm saying that where the neighbor hits the farmer doesn't matter (just as where the farmer hits the neighbor doesn't matter).  Whenever one hits the other before the neighbor steals a mushroom,  that side wins.  Otherwise the game ends with a win for the neighbor if he or she can reach the top (mushroom) row without being hit.

Comment: No, if the neighbor hits the farmer, the farmer also must back off. It is mentioned in the wording.

Comment: It's still unclear what "back off" means.  Does it mean (a) the game is over and the other player wins? (b) the player must return to their original position (E7 for the farmer, F1 for the neighbor)? (c) the player must move away from their opponent in whatever direction they want (and is available)? (d) the player must move away from their opponent in as opposite a direction as possible? (e) the player must move away to the most distant square from their opponent?

Comment: @BrianTung: whoever reaches the "opponent" (that is, if they find themselves in the same square block), the game ends.

Comment: @hardmath yes, you are right, I didn't read your comment carefully. To clarify, the "game" ends in any of the 3 cases: 1. The farmer reaches the neighbor (walks on his square). In this case, the neighbor has to leave and go home. 2. The neighbor reaches the farmer, even once (walks on his square). Then the farmer has to admit he lost, and let him get the mushrooms! 3. The neighbor reaches one (any) mushroom before the farmer manages to stop him. I hope it is clear now. Will add it also to the description.

Comment: are they forced to move on every turn, or can they choose to not move ?

Comment: @mercio yes, they must move on every turn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neighbor can win.  He starts to E1 and claims the distant opposition.  If the farmer moves forward, so does the neighbor.  If the farmer moves sideways the neighbor moves diagonally forward on the side away from the farmer.  Now the farmer must move toward the neighbor and the neighbor can move in front of the farmer an even number of spaces away, maintaining the opposition.  Again the farmer must move sideways one way and the neighbor moves diagonally forward on the other side.

A game might go
E1  D6
F2  E6
E2  D6
F3  E5
E3  D5
F4  E6
E4  D6
F5  and the neighbor can get the F mushroom

Comment: Ross, thank you. However, after F5, the farmer can respond with E7. Then the neighbor can't go to any of E6 or F6, so he chooses E5. What could be the next moves?

Comment: Yes, the neighbor chooses E5.  Then the farmer has to play D7, allowing F6 or F7 allowing D6

Comment: @RossMillikan Good morning. But how do you prove that this strategy works for every move that the neighbor does? I understand that Carlos' question refers to "every" scenario, right? Thank you.

Comment: @Samuel:  There are lots of books on chess endgames that deal with this.  A real proof could be done by the computer chess programs.  Opposition and distant opposition are well known to work.

Comment: The two solutions submitted are contradicting! Since this is a nice and interesting problem, can anyone explain in more detail the idea behind them? I have tried @RossMillikan solution with alternative moves at various points but the neighbor doesn't always win (maybe I am doing something wrong, since I don't know the logic). But my understanding is that, if the neighbor (for example) has a strategy, then this must work on all occasions; that is, by every one of his moves, he must "force" the opponent to do a specific move that leads to the deadly position. Isn't it so? Thank you very much!

Comment: @PradeepSuny:  The neighbor wins by forcing the farmer to move to one side, then moving forward on the other.  He will be able to make an end run around the farmer.  The neighbor wants to be in front of the farmer and an even number of spaces away, which is why the first move is to E1

Comment: @RossMillikan: Great solution - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, unless the farmer takes a deliberately bad path, he will always be able to hit the neighbor. Here are sample moves juxtaposed. In the 2nd example, the farmer could have avoided being hit by taking a different path. The neighbor can only be hit or move to places to avoid being hit but he cannot get past the farmer if the farmer moves wisely.

N1: 2F 3E 4D

F1: 6F 5E 4D-HIT

N2: 2E 3D 3C 4C-HIT

F2: 6E 5D 4C

N3: 2E 3D 3C 4D

F3: 6E 5D 5C 4D-HIT